# Refreshing an ExpandableListView from within the adapter on Android

Tags: android, refresh, expandablelistview

I'm having trouble on how to refresh an `ExpandableListView` from within one of its childViews.

The listView contains a list of files, and I want to offer a possibility to delete those files. But after a deletion is performed, the `ExpandableListView` needs to be refreshed. 
I implemented my own adapter which extends the `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. It seems there is no way to get my parent object from within the overwritten `getChildView()` method to send a `notifyDataSetChanged()`. :-s

I thought about sending an intent to my activity which contains information on the state of the groups (collapsed/expanded) and to refresh on receive, but even for this I would need the `ExpandableListView` object.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Be well
S.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to

- remove the corresponding item from your adapter
- and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Then the ListView will reload the data.

Comment: Thanks. But doing this is my basic problem. :) I need to refresh *from within* the adapter.

Comment: it just by design doesn't work the way I tried to do it. thanks for your help.